# "set-variable = innodb_thread_concurrency=4" or "innodb_thread_concurrency=4"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, my.cnf

Based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow/20860), the asker wrote:

```
set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=2M
set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=500K
set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=500K
set-variable = innodb_thread_concurrency=2
set-variable = innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

All of the variable has `set-variable`. I've tested this way on MySQL 5.1 standard install, and it works fine.

But I dont like it that way because it too long.

Lots of other guide including in MySQL website didn't say about using `set-variable`. Even in MyISAM setting example (MySQL 5.1), it only use `thread_concurrency = 10`

I've just installed MySQL 5.5 on new server and now is the time for configuration.

So, do MySQL really need `set-variable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL works fine without the `set-variable` in the my.cnf file